# Help with exchange integral interactions!

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry

A single determinant configuration constructed in a basis with 7 spatial orbitals has the following exchange integral interaction energy terms:
-2K12 -K13 -K23 -K14 -K24
(i) Draw a configuration that has exactly these exchange energy terms.

attempt:
1st orbital -> 2e-
2nd orbital -> 2e-
3rd orbital -> 1e-
4th orbital -> 1e-

(ii) Write down the full energy expression using the one-electron (hii),
Coulomb (Jij), and exchange (Kij) integral contributions.

attempt:
[image]

Comment: Your question looks like a homework or exam question. Could you elaborate your question so we can help you with the answer? I think there is a guide to submit this kind of questions but I can not point you to it right now.

Comment: Hint.  Remember that the exchange integral $K_{ij}$ are cero if both spin-orbitals have different spin functions.